# How to use promise in AWS Lambda?

Tags: javascript, lambda, promise

I try to create a lambda function to post a message in Slack.

```
const { WebClient } = require('@slack/client');

const token = '...';
const web = new WebClient(token);
const channel = '#...';

exports.handler = (event) => {
    console.log('First');

    web.chat.postMessage({ 
        channel: channel, 
        username: '...',
        icon_emoji: '...', 
        text: 'Hello world'
    })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Ok');

            return {
                statusCode: 200
            };
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error', error);

            return {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: error
            };
        });

    console.log('Finish');
};
```

My question : how I can do to return the return in my `then` and `catch` function ?

Actually, lambda return `null`. (Ok, because I haven't return in my main function). So If my function failed, Lambda return still an answer (200).

Maybe I don't use correctly Lambda and Promise. Moreover I don'y really understand the keyword `await` before `(event) => {`. I'm forced to remove it otherwise my function does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You probably need a `return` in front of your promise chain (`web.chat.postMessage(…).then(…).catch(…)`).

Comment: "I'm forced to remove it otherwise my function does not work." Which version of node.js did you set on the AWS lambda?

Comment: I use Node.js 8.10

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function will need to return a response.
For example if you construct your response as:

`const response = { 
     statusCode: 200, 
     body: JSON.stringify(somedata) 
 }`,

```
somedata can be a message if you do not return any important data.
```

then you do as a return `callback(null, response)`. Btw you are missing callback from the functions parameter.